# SingleFileStore [Infinispan][AdvancedLoadWriteStore]

Tags: java, infinispan

can someone shows me or send me an example of how to use the class SingleFileStore for infinispan in order to save my data into a singleFileStore ?
i found that this class implements AdvancedLoadWriteStore and i don't know how to override the methode process. there is a proof code source  of infinispan.
hank you for your help , im blocked :(

my goal is to save my infinspan cache into a file and read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SingleFileStore works out of the box by just adding it to a cache either declaratively:

```
<local-cache>
    <persistence>
        <file-store/>
    </persistence>
</local-cache>
```

or programmatically:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.persistence()
     .passivation(false)
     .addSingleFileStore();
```

Bear in mind that this is a binary file store.
If you need to store the data in a particular format, you will have to write your own custom store.

Comment: and if the file is binary , how can i read the content of this file with infinispan ? there is other configuration to add ?

Comment: can you confirme me please that infinispan will be able to load the data of my file automatically in the startup of my application ? because in my project , we are using file JMS and web services and im afraid that the call of this web services or consumption message will passe before the load of data with infinispan.. – user3822342 4 mins ago   edit

Comment: last question please, we can generet this file in th classpath of the project et not in the disc ? because may be we'll have to deploy our application in the cloud !